# How to append the list in a dictionary into its own column?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, key-value-store

I have a dictionary with lists as values as you can see here:

```
my_dict  = {1: ['Home', 'Stories'], 2: ['Sounds', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Stories'], 3: ['Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series'], 4: [ 'Home', 'Home', 'Home'], 5: ['Home', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Cancellation Flow'], 6: ['My Account', 'My Account']}
```

I would like to turn the lists within these dictionaries into string and append them into their own column.

This is what I tried so far, but it does not work as the values in the dictionary are lists.

```
keys_list = list(my_dict.keys())
values_list = list(my_dict.values())

df_keyvalues = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': keys_list, 'Column2': values_list})

df_keyvalues
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
User       List
1          'Home', 'Stories'
2          'Sounds', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Stories'
3          'Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series'
4          'Home', 'Home', 'Home'
5          'Home', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Cancellation Flow'
6          'My Account', 'My Account'
```

Comment: What type of `List` column you actually expect?

Answer (score 2):

With `delimiter.join(list)` you can join your lists as a string:

```
keys_list = list(my_dict.keys())
values_list = [", ".join(i) for i in list(my_dict.values())]
df_keyvalues = pd.DataFrame({'User': keys_list, 'List': values_list})
```

Is this what your are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Dataframe in order to produce that output

```
my_dict = {
    1: ['Home', 'Stories'],
    2: ['Sounds', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Stories'],
    3: ['Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series'],
    4: ['Home', 'Home', 'Home'],
    5: ['Home', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Cancellation Flow'],
    6: ['My Account', 'My Account']
}

PAD = 10

def quote(s):
    return f"'{s}'"

print('{:<{}}List'.format('User', PAD))

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print(f'{k:<{PAD}}{", ".join(map(quote, v))}')
```

**Output:**

```
User      List
1         'Home', 'Stories'
2         'Sounds', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Stories'
3         'Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series', 'Journeys / Series'
4         'Home', 'Home', 'Home'
5         'Home', 'Stories', 'Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Cancellation Flow'
6         'My Account', 'My Account'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
keys_list = list(my_dict.keys())
values_list = list(my_dict.values())

df_keyvalues = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': keys_list, 'Column2': values_list})

#This will convert list to a string
df_keyvalues['Column2'] = df_keyvalues['Column2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))

df_keyvalues
```

but yes it will not be "Home","Stories" it will be Home,Stories, i hope that will not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your intension is to convert the strings in list to a single string(in which the strings in list will be separated by comma in result string), the following is the solution. no need to explicitly mention list() when using dict.keys() and dict.values() as both keys() and values() functions return lists only.

```
keys_list = my_dict.keys()
values_list = my_dict.values()
new_list=[",".join(i) for i in values_list]
df_keyvalues = pd.DataFrame({'User': keys_list, 'List': new_list})

print(df_keyvalues.to_string(index=False))
```

output would be single string but not strings separated by commas.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC5RE.png)